# How to update pip and keep the new version of pip portable (=use relative path to python.exe)?

Tags: python, pip, portable-applications

I use WinPython as portable app on Windows and get following hint:

```
A new release of pip is available: 23.1.2 -> 23.2.1
[notice] To update, run: python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

If I run the command as suggested, the new version of pip stores the absolute path to python.exe.

If I **move my IDE folder to another location**, **pip does not work any more**:

```
pip list
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"C:\python_env\App\WinPython\python-3.11.1.amd64\python.exe"  "D:\eis\python_env\App\WinPython\python-3.11.1.amd64\Scripts\pip.exe" list': The system cannot find the file specified.
```

=> Is there a way to tell pip to store a relative path to python.exe instead of an absolute one, so that pip remains portable?

=> Or is there some configuration file that I could fix after installing pip, for example some pip._pth file? Where to put it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WinPyton comes with a script file that fixes portability:

WinPython/scripts/make_winpython_movable.bat

Answer (score 0):

You can use PIP_PREFIX environment variable

```
export PIP_PREFIX=~/.local/pip
```

This will set the PIP_PREFIX environment variable to the directory ~/.local/pip. This directory is created by Python when you install pip, and it is located in your home directory.

Once you have set the PIP_PREFIX environment variable, pip will store all of its files in the directory ~/.local/pip.

```
In the Edit environment variable dialog box, add the following path to the end of the Value field:

;~/.local/pip
```

Test it using : echo $PIP_PREFIX

The output of this command should be the path to the directory `~/.local/pip.`

Comment: Thank you. I want to keep the files pip.exe etc. where they are. However, pip.exe should reference a different python.exe. What would be the corresponding commands for Windows?